The "A"s mnemonic for instrument approaches
I used the 6 As mnemonic when I got my instrument rating. I remember them as

ATIS
Altimeter
Avionics
Approach Briefing
Airplane (approach checklist)
Align (DG, ADI)

Similarly to the 5 Ts, having mantras or mnemonics was a helpful way to stay productive even when task-saturated. But while I can find a lot of sources for the canonical 5 Ts, the only thing I see for the As is this article. Respectfully, I think a key feature of the As as I learned them is that you set the avionics up first, then use the approach briefing as a cross-check, so I don't like that presentation as much.
Can anyone point me to resources that list the 6 As as I remember them or a similar mnemonic? I've gotten back to flight instructing after years away, and I'd prefer to share a better resource than "My instructor told me to write this down." I did my instrument rating at Embry-Riddle in 2000, so it could have been something formal there, or just something my instructor heard from his instructor, and so on.
Thanks!

OT, but there is an easy way to memorize morse code, which can be useful for identifying navaids without having to gawk at the little box with dots and dashes. You create a list of phrases with a cadence that matches the letter. Ex: F=Funny Handle: ..-.  B=Brown Chocolate: -... C=Charlie Charlie: -.-. D= Dag nabbit! : _..  E= EH?: . G=Good good boy": _ _ .   I was able to recall those from memory and I haven't thought of them for many years.

when I was preparing for my instrument checkride, I found that mnemonic in a video from Jason Miller's "finer points" youtube channel (although it was only 5 As, it was missing the 'allign')
